# Does any one know of a atolf c function?

Tags: c, string, double, type-conversion, atof

I am looking for a function similar to `atol` (char * to long int) but `atofl` (char to long double), does anyone know of a library that does this, or a simple way to do this, since using
`atof` on "0.00000005" casts off the 5?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtod/) that does what you want.

Comment: char to long double is `strtold`... though the OP has already selected your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think you have use the wrong argument of printf, so you only saw the console giving you "0.000000", you can try

```
printf("%0.10f", atof(str_num));
```

to show the your number, and you will find what you want.